# "... && ... || ..." (short-circuiting boolean) not identical to "if ...; then ...; else ...; fi"

Tags: bash, conditional-statements, codeblocks

I have just had unexpected result from writing the alternative form of if/then/else blocks.

```
> #this is the behaviour I expect:  
> if [[ 1 -eq 1 ]]; then echo "good"; false; else   echo "bad"; fi
good

> #assuming no error in the first block these brackets behave okay as well:
> [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { echo "good"; } || { echo "bad"; }
good

> #this however allows the process to jump into the first AND second block
> [[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { echo "good"; false; } || { echo "bad"; }
good
bad
```

Why does the curly brace method pass the process to the second block. I'm aware there's some statements that there must be a `;` before the end of the block, but if bash blocks behave badly on an error condition as a last statement these blocks seem "unsafe" to use.

Comment: `foo && bar || baz` is perfectly safe, as long as you don't try to use them as something they aren't. They aren't `if; then; else`.

Comment: This is why http://shellcheck.net/ flags `foo && bar || baz` with the warning [SC2015](https://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck/wiki/SC2015), to dissuade people who are using it without knowing what it actually does.

Comment: (What does this have to do with code blocks? It's the same for *any* command; no matter if it's a single command that echos something and then returns false, or separate `echo` and `false` commands in a block).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `&&` and `||` operators in the shell work with the return value (exit code) of each statement. In a compound statement within `{ }`, the exit status of the last command is the important one.

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { echo "good"; } || { echo "bad"; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
true && true || true
```

So `true && true` evaluates to `true`, and the shell "short-circuits" (i.e. doesn't evaluate) the `{ echo "bad"; }` because `true || anything` is true.

```
[[ 1 -eq 1 ]] && { echo "good"; false; } || { echo "bad"; }
```

is equivalent to:

```
true && false || true
```

In this case, `true && false` evaluates to false, and the shell has to evaluate full expression.

The `if`/`else` code takes the first branch, because the exit code of `[[ 1 -eq 1 ]]` is `0` (the same as `true` in the shell).

Answer (score 2):

Because the function of `||` is to execute its right hand side if its left hand side returns nonzero, which `false` does.

`&&`/`||` is not an if/else, nor is it a `?:` trinary operator - it's a chained pair of separate operations.